# How do I do a case insensitive regular expression in Go?

Tags: regex, go

I could write my regular expression to handle both cases, such as `regexp.Compile("[a-zA-Z]")`, but my regular expression is constructed from a string given by the user:

```
reg, err := regexp.Compile(strings.Replace(s.Name, " ", "[ \\._-]", -1))
```

Where `s.Name` is the name.  Which could be something like 'North by Northwest'.  Now, the most apparent solution to me would be to walk through each character of `s.Name` and write '[nN]' for each letter:

```golang
    for i := 0; i < len(s.Name); i++ {
      if s.Name[i] == " " {
        fmt.Fprintf(str, "%s[ \\._-]", str);
      } else {
        fmt.Fprintf(str, "%s[%s%s]", str, strings.ToLower(s.Name[i]), strings.ToUpper(s.Name[i]))
      }
    }
```

But I feel this is a rather non-elegant solution.  Speed is not really a concern, but I need to know if there is another way.

Answer (score 266, accepted):

You can set a case-insensitive flag as the first item in the regex.

You do this by adding `"(?i)"` to the beginning of a regex.

```
reg, err := regexp.Compile("(?i)"+strings.Replace(s.Name, " ", "[ \\._-]", -1))
```

For a fixed regex it would look like this.

```
r := regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)CaSe`)
```

For more information about flags, search the
[`regexp/syntax`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax) package documentation
(or the [syntax documentation](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax))
 for the term "flags".

Comment: But I found this is too slow, when there are many data. Because of invoking unicode.SimpleFold in regexp.Match, so I suggest changing the letters to upper and then using regexp to match. This is speed.

The Following is time data:

```
#By (?i) regexp to ignore case
XCMP/bin/otacmp -o BSP_2.2.0.html -f BSP/frameworks -f Code/frameworks  1271.94s user 7.32s system 97% cpu 21:54.95 total

#By toUpper and match
XCMP/bin/otacmp -o BSP_2.2.0.html -f BSP/frameworks -f Code/frameworks  263.87s user 8.99s system 110% cpu 4:06.44 total
```

Comment: It looks like slow performance for case-insensitive regexp was a known bug that was fixed in the months following: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13288

Comment: Depending on your use, you may find `regexp.QuoteMeta` useful.

Comment: I wish this (how to use flags) was clear from the documentation. The regexp package godoc doesn't even have the word "flag." And nowhere in the syntax doc does it say how you set a flag is by prefixing your expression with it.

Answer (score 46):

You can add a `(?i)` at the beginning of the pattern to make it case insensitive.

[Reference](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)

Answer (score 11):

I'm not too familiar with Go, but according to this example: http://play.golang.org/p/WgpNhwWWuW

You need to prefix your regex statement with `(?i)`

Answer (score 5):

Use the `i` flag. Quoting the tip [documentation](http://tip.golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/):

> Grouping:

```
(re)           numbered capturing group
(?P<name>re)   named & numbered capturing group
(?:re)         non-capturing group
(?flags)       set flags within current group; non-capturing
(?flags:re)    set flags during re; non-capturing
```

> Flag syntax is xyz (set) or -xyz (clear) or xy-z (set xy, clear z). The flags are:

```
i              case-insensitive (default false)
m              multi-line mode: ^ and $ match begin/end line in addition to begin/end text (default false)
s              let . match \n (default false)
U              ungreedy: swap meaning of x* and x*?, x+ and x+?, etc (default false)
```

Comment: Where in the code should I put these i, m, s and U?

Comment: This answer is as unhelpful as the documentation. Thankfully, there's a working example below.