# How to write to a file in golang

Tags: go

i am trying to write to to a file. i read the whole content of the file and now i want to change the content of the file based on some word that i have got from the file. but when i check, the content of the file, it is still the same and it has not change. this is what i used

```
if strings.Contains(string(read), sam) {
    fmt.Println("this file contain that word")
    temp := strings.ToUpper(sam)
    fmt.Println(temp)
    err := ioutil.WriteFile(fi.Name(), []byte(temp), 0644)
} else {
    fmt.Println(" the word is not in the file")
}
```

Comment: Are you checking the value of `err`? I think this would tell you what is going wrong...

Comment: im just trying to write the content of temp back to the file, but when   i check my file, the content has not been change

Comment: I understand what you want to do. I'm just asking you to check if `err` is `nil` or if it has another value. And in that case, what the value is.

Comment: the code is not complete, i used this func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    } and after my snipper i have check(err). if it is nil then there is a problem

Comment: I think it would help you and us if you provide the fully working code that is as small as possible. By stripping out code that is not needed, you might find the problem yourself. If not, we have a better chance to find the error.

Comment: if matched{
     read,err:= ioutil.ReadFile(path)
     //fmt.Println(string(read))
     fmt.Println(" This is the name of the file",fi.Name())
     if strings.Contains(string(read), sam){
      fmt.Println("this file contain that word")
      Value:=strings.ToUpper(sam)
      fmt.Println(Value)
      err=ioutil.WriteFile(fi.Name(),[]byte(Value),0644)
      } else {
      fmt.Println(" the word is not in the file")
      }
     check(err)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Considering that your call to [`ioutil.WriteFile()`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#WriteFile) is consistent with what is used in "[Go by Example: Writing Files](https://gobyexample.com/writing-files)", this should work.

But that Go by example article check the err just after the write call.

You check the err outside the scope of your test:

```
    if matched {
        read, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
        //fmt.Println(string(read))
        fmt.Println(" This is the name of the file", fi.Name())
        if strings.Contains(string(read), sam) {
            fmt.Println("this file contain that word")
            Value := strings.ToUpper(sam)
            fmt.Println(Value)
            err = ioutil.WriteFile(fi.Name(), []byte(Value), 0644)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(" the word is not in the file")
        }
        check(err)   <===== too late
    }
```

The err you are testing is the one you got when reading the file (`ioutil.ReadFile`), because of [blocks and scope](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Blocks).

You need to check the error right after the Write call

```
            err = ioutil.WriteFile(fi.Name(), []byte(Value), 0644)
            check(err)   <===== too late
```

---

Since WriteFile overwrite the all file, you could [strings.Replace()](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replace) to replace your word by its upper case equivalent:

```
r := string(read)
r = strings.Replace(r, sam, strings.ToUpper(sam), -1)
err := ioutil.WriteFile(fi.Name(), []byte(r), 0644)
```

---

For a **replace which is case insensitive**, use a regexp as in "[How do I do a case insensitive regular expression in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15326479/6309)".
The, use [`func (*Regexp) ReplaceAllString`](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.ReplaceAllString):

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("(?i)\\b"+sam+"\\b")
r = re.ReplaceAllString(r, strings.ToUpper(sam))
err := ioutil.WriteFile(fi.Name(), []byte(r), 0644)
```

Note the `\b`: **[word boundary](https://github.com/StefanSchroeder/Golang-Regex-Tutorial/blob/master/01-chapter1.markdown#anchor-and-boundaries)** to find the any *word* starting and ending with `sam` content (instead of finding substrings *containing* `sam` content).
If you want to replace substrings, simply drop the `\b`:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("(?i)"+sam)
```

Comment: well in the initial file it is not change. it is lower case, that is it is still the same value i read

Comment: I agree. Could you check err just after Write, to see if there is an exception?

Comment: i just did but it does not throw me any exception. the other code just work fine but when i check the file, the content is the same

Comment: @user3841581 can you print `fi.Name()` and make sure it is the right file path? Or do you see another file with the same name created by your program?

Comment: @user3841581 can you replace `fi.Name()` by the full complete path of the file, just for testing? `ioutil.WriteFile("/full/path/of/the/file", []byte(Value), 0644)`

Comment: it worked but overwrote the whole file and change it to the value. what could be the problem here?

Comment: @user3841581 that is what WriteFile does: it truncate the existing file and replace its content by default.

Comment: is there a way to just replace the value which i found in the the file to its upper case? without changing the content of the whole file

Comment: the problem is that it replace the string use for the test but again it has to be written to the file. and it that case it does overwrite the whole file.

Comment: @user3841581 try it: it overwrite the all file with its all content (including the string replaced in it)

Comment: yes, i changed the what i received and converted it to uppercase and i then use the replace while passing and it still replace everything

Comment: @user3841581 that is the goal: to replace everything. It is ok since 'r' represents the full content of the file read.

Comment: your last snippet works but it is case sensitive. is there a way to make it case insensitive. for example, if i send as input UpDate and in the file there is update, is there a way that the input can match the word in the file?

Comment: Thank you VonC ; however,how can i modifie your snippet to include a count to keep track on the words found

Comment: @user3841581 that would be another question, in which you can detail the code you have and what is missing. You can close this one by selecting an answer.

Comment: when i try it with the regrex, it doesnt pick up the word nor change them.

Comment: this is the snippet i have but it does not :if matched{
     read,err:= ioutil.ReadFile(path)
     //fmt.Println(string(read))
     fmt.Println(" This is the name of the file",fi.Name())
     if strings.Contains(string(read), sam){
      fmt.Println("this file contain that word")
      r := string(read)
  re := regexp.MustCompile("(?i)\\b"+sam+"\\b")
  r = re.ReplaceAllString(r, strings.ToUpper(sam))
  err := ioutil.WriteFile(fi.Name(), []byte(r), 0644)
      check(err)
      
      } else {
      fmt.Println(" the word is not in the file")
      }     
   fmt.Println(err)  }

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you want to do. My best guess is something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func UpdateWord(filename string, data, word []byte) (int, error) {
    n := 0
    f, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        return n, err
    }
    uWord := bytes.ToUpper(word)
    if len(word) < len(uWord) {
        err := errors.New("Upper case longer than lower case:" + string(word))
        return n, err
    }
    if len(word) > len(uWord) {
        uWord = append(uWord, bytes.Repeat([]byte{' '}, len(word))...)[:len(word)]
    }
    off := int64(0)
    for {
        i := bytes.Index(data[off:], word)
        if i < 0 {
            break
        }
        off += int64(i)
        _, err = f.WriteAt(uWord, off)
        if err != nil {
            return n, err
        }
        n++
        off += int64(len(word))
    }
    f.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return n, err
    }
    return n, nil
}

func main() {
    // Test file
    filename := `ltoucase.txt`

    // Create test file
    lcase := []byte(`update a bc def ghij update klmno pqrstu update vwxyz update`)
    perm := os.FileMode(0644)
    err := ioutil.WriteFile(filename, lcase, perm)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // Read test file
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(data))

    // Update word in test file
    word := []byte("update")
    n, err := UpdateWord(filename, data, word)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(n, err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(filename, string(word), n)
    data, err = ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

Output:

```
update a bc def ghij update klmno pqrstu update vwxyz update
ltoucase.txt update 4
UPDATE a bc def ghij UPDATE klmno pqrstu UPDATE vwxyz UPDATE
```

Comment: it does work but it is case sensitive, so what will happen if i send UpDate, the word will not being found in the file. is there a way to make it in such a way it should still not being case sensitive?

Comment: is there a way to include the regrex function to your function so that it is case insensitive?